# Adding Object to an empty cell

Tags: arrays, object, cell

I have a question about adding objects to an empty array cell.

I have a couple of objects that I created Student (String name, double GPA)

```
Student stu1 = new Student("Paul", 2.0);
Student stu2 = new Student ("John", 3.0);
Student stu3 = new Student("Simon", 2.0);
```

I have a classroom object that creates an array

```
Classroom class1 = new Classroom(3);
```

The array in Classroom is private, so I am adding the students using

```
public boolean add(Student aStudent)

class1.add(stu1);
class1.add(stu2);
class1.add(stu3);
```

This method checks for the next empty cell and then puts the Student object in. If the array is full, it returns false. Those are the conditions in the assignment I am doing.

Here is the full add method

```
public boolean add(Student aStudent) {

for(int i = 0; i <=(students.length-1); i++)
    {
    if (students[i] == null)
        students[i] = aStudent;
    }
    return true; //not important for my question

}
```

I also have a get method that returns the reference of a Student object

```
public Student getStudent(int position)
```

And finally I have a getName and getGPA method to return the name and GPA of the getStudent method above

If I run the code and ask to output the name of the three Student Objects saved in the array,

```
System.out.println(stu1.getName(class1.getStudent(0)));
System.out.println(stu1.getName(class1.getStudent(1)));
System.out.println(stu1.getName(class1.getStudent(2)));
```

I get:

Paul
Paul
Paul

I don't understand why I get this output. Did I code the add method right? It seems logical,: if the cell is null, then add the value to it. If not, loop to the next cell and check.

Comment: Why are you always doing stu1.getName instead of using all 3 stu instances.

Comment: We've all been innocent victims of copy and paste :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this:

```
if (students[0] == null)
    students[0] = aStudent;
```

is supposed to be this:

```
if (students[i] == null)
    students[i] = aStudent;
```

Comment: beat me to the punch :)

Comment: Thanks. That was a typo from my part. It did not change the output though. Still Paul Paul Paul.